# Web GUI for C++ console application?

Tags: c++, html, user-interface

I have a C++ project which I need to have some sort of GUI for, and I don't have time to learn something like the Win32 API (or qt or gtk for that matter).

So my question is:
What options do I have for building a web-based GUI for my C++ console application? For example, is it possible to use HTML for the GUI and somehow embed my C++ code into the webpage?

Thanks.

Comment: A GUI system being web-based does not save you from learning it. If you don't have time to learn something in a knowledge based profession then you don't have time to do the task.

Comment: I'm disappointed. If you ask such a broad, ambitious question and receive 6 answers in minutes (on average), could you take the time to respond? Give us your comments; upvote the answers that you think are helpful. Accept an answer if it solves your problem. If you are just letting this fly you are wasting our time.

Answer (score 4):

Did you consider using the [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/) web toolkit? It is a C++ library to give a Web user interface to a C++ program.

You could also use some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/).

Answer (score 3):

Check [CppCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net) framework. It makes it easy to implement Web services in C++, handle requests and output responses, also with HTML templates. Simply, server-side embedded C++ scripting capability.

Answer (score 1):

Web based gui's run on the client side and code is limited to Javascript. To run C++ on your site you would need to set up a server that can make calls to the C++ code via the console and accept the output from console. Then you would have to communicate that information to the client using page posts or ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this is what you want, but there is

- PoCo http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPServer.html

  It has a HTTPServer/HTTPRequestHandler model that supports a kind of server kind scripting in C++ (like `<?php ... ?>` but with C++); see **[here](http://pocoproject.org/docs/PageCompilerUserGuide.html)** for sample:

  > ```
  > <%@ page class="TimeHandler" %>
  > <%!
  >     #include "Poco/DateTime.h"
  >     #include "Poco/DateTimeFormatter.h"
  >     #include "Poco/DateTimeFormat.h"
  >
  >
  >     using Poco::DateTime;
  >     using Poco::DateTimeFormatter;
  >     using Poco::DateTimeFormat;
  > %>
  >
  > <%
  >     DateTime now;
  >     std::string dt(DateTimeFormatter::format(now,  DateTimeFormat::SORTABLE_FORMAT));
  > %>
  > <html>
  > <head>
  > <title>Time Sample</title>
  > </head>
  > <body>
  > <h1>Time Sample</h1>
  > <p><%= dt %></p>
  > </body>
  > </html>
  > ```

  - http://pocoproject.org/documentation/PoCoOverview.pdf (section 2.9):

    > #### The C++ Server Page Compiler
    >
    > Page Compiler is a command line tool that translates HTML files (and other
    >   kinds of files) into C++ classes for use with the HTTP server provided by the
    >   Net library. The source files can contain special directives that allow
    >   embedding of C++ code. The syntax of these directives is based on the
    >   syntax used for Java Server Pages (JSP) and Active Server Pages (ASP). This
    >   makes it very easy to build web applications in C++ with the POCO C++
    >   Libraries.
- **[Klone Embedded Webserver](http://www.koanlogic.com/klone/)** doing similar things
- [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) is able to compile extensive C++ code via LLVM intermediate code to javascript. This could be used to use existing library functions running entirely in the webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

Does the console app need some sort of interaction or does it just take a bunch of commandline parameters, run and dump some output?

If you just want to create a web form to enter the values, run the app in a shell and format the results into a webpage - that's easy, suggest something like Python to write the wrapper to launch the program but anything will do.

If you need to interact with the app from the web while it's running see [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

Answer (score 0):

PHP's got [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) which will execute a command as if from the command line. Python and Ruby frameworks probably support popen on some level, though I have no specific information.